# SharePoint 2013 Calendar getSelector is undefined in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, calendar, sharepoint-2013

I have a SharePoint 2013 publishing website with a calendar web part. I want the calendar to be a group calendar, but SharePoint doesn't retain default users for the calendar. So I've been using a method to populate the calendar when the page loads. It's described in detail here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/meamcs/archive/2013/04/10/sharepoint-group-calendar-adding-default-users.aspx. 
This works in Chrome, Opera, Safari, and FireFox, but not IE (I've tested 5 through 11 using IE's emulator)

The method described in the link gets a context id from the calendar html tags and uses SharePoint's JavaScript library to load the extra users from predefined XML. 
I loaded the XML from a file on the server. The HTML for the web part looks like:

```
<div id="ctl00_ctl43_g_cc24db55_d224_4ea9_b770_4c2edd2c083e_ctl01_ctl00_ctl00" class="ms-acal-rootdiv" ctxid="WPQ3">...</div>
```

The ctxid is used to reference the calendar. However, in IE, the ctxid property isn't there! So, I use the previous element to get the ctxid instead:

```
<div class="ms-acal-error" id="WPQ3_err" style="display:none"></div>
```

Here's my code for loading the users into the calendar:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){
    var ctxid; 
    if ( $(".ms-acal-rootdiv").attr("ctxid") ){
        ctxid = $(".ms-acal-rootdiv").attr("ctxid");                                    
    }
    else if ( $(".ms-acal-error").attr("id") ){
        ctxid = $(".ms-acal-error").attr("id").replace("_err","");
    }                                                                   
    SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarSelector.instance().getSelector(1,ctxid).selectEntities(xml,true);
 },"sp.ribbon.js");
```

IE throws an error: "Unable to get property 'selectEntities' of undefined or null reference", and IE does return undefined for getSelector(1,ctxid). I've also tried hard-coding the value for ctxid with no success.

I've been looking on Google for a couple of hours now and haven't found any solutions. Most blogs that describe this process, have comments from other users asking about this issue but no one has answered those questions.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you positive `ctxid` contains the correct value? Does this work if you hard-code the string into the method?

Comment: I've tried hard-coding the value as "WPQ3" but IE still returns the "undefined" error...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this constitutes an "answer" and I am unsure if this will help others but it seems that the problem is fixed!

So the problem seems to have resolved itself after I fixed another issue: IE was also throwing the error:

```
Sys.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range. Parameter name: serverRelativeUrl sp.runtime.js
```

Everything else continued to work on the page, so I initially continued focusing on the problem at hand. Today I decided to focus on the Sys.ArgumentException error instead: In my code, some subsites required information from a list in its parent site. To get the site collection URL, I used SharePoint's **L_MenuBase_Url** variable. However, I found that the Sys.ArgumentException error was thrown because the **L_MenuBase_Url** variable (set by SharePoint) was empty ("").

This, somehow, was caused by SharePoint executing this code:

```
angular.element("#home_content").scope()._init()
```

before the scope finished loading (I think). As I was working to fix the error above I didn't see this error:

```
Object doesn't support property or method '_init'
```

So I logged the out put of

```
angular.element("#home_content").scope()
```

and, sure enough, it returned undefined. This error was not occurring in any other browser...Anyway, once I ensured that scope() was defined, by using a timer and waiting for scope() to not be undefined, before executing _init() everything worked (including the calendar and the L_Menu_BaseUrl variable.

I probably should have fixed the other two errors before asking the question. Sorry about that!

Thanks for the help though